# Geolocation API removed from unsecured origins in Chrome 50

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-geolocation

Is there any fallback option for Geolocation API of google ?

Starting from Google Chrome version 50, all requests from unsecured origins to Geolocation API are returning error code 1.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only?hl=en

As a result, I am not able to locate the current location of users from chrome browser.

Don't want to move my server from HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: Try [gpsha.re](https://gpsha.re). You can redirect your location requests to that page.

Answer (score 0):

This guy make some fallback when it occours.
http://jsfiddle.net/gogs/jwt9f1o3/

```
var apiGeolocationSuccess = function(position) {
    alert("API geolocation success!\n\nlat = " + position.coords.latitude + "\nlng = " + position.coords.longitude);
};

var tryAPIGeolocation = function() {
    jQuery.post( "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=AIzaSyDCa1LUe1vOczX1hO_iGYgyo8p_jYuGOPU", function(success) {
        apiGeolocationSuccess({coords: {latitude: success.location.lat, longitude: success.location.lng}});
  })
  .fail(function(err) {
    alert("API Geolocation error! \n\n"+err);
  });
};

var browserGeolocationSuccess = function(position) {
    alert("Browser geolocation success!\n\nlat = " + position.coords.latitude + "\nlng = " + position.coords.longitude);
};

var browserGeolocationFail = function(error) {
  switch (error.code) {
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      alert("Browser geolocation error !\n\nTimeout.");
      break;
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      if(error.message.indexOf("Only secure origins are allowed") == 0) {
        tryAPIGeolocation();
      }
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      alert("Browser geolocation error !\n\nPosition unavailable.");
      break;
  }
};

var tryGeolocation = function() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        browserGeolocationSuccess,
      browserGeolocationFail,
      {maximumAge: 50000, timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
  }
};

tryGeolocation();
```